# Windows 10 does not show my GoPro Camera MTP device in explorer/my computer

Tags: windows, windows-10, gopro

When I connect my GoPro hero black 7 camera to Win 8.1, I see the device in MyComputer and I can browse files.

But when I connect it to my Windows 10 laptop, I see the MTP device in device manager and drivers work properly, no errors with the device. But I do not see the camera in explorer/my computer, so I can't browse and copy files.
I tried: reinstall USB driver, connect to other USB port, restrt camera and laptop. Nothing changes: I see normal functioning MTP device but I can't browse files, because there is no new disk/device in explorer.
So how to browse files.

Answer (score 0):

Check that you have these subkeys under HKLM...\DelegateFolders

```
    Hive: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\MyComputer\
    NameSpace\DelegateFolders


Name                                   Property
----                                   --------
{289AF617-1CC3-42A6-926C-E6A863F0E3BA} (default) : DLNA Media Servers Data Source
{35786D3C-B075-49b9-88DD-029876E11C01} (default) : Portable Devices
{9113A02D-00A3-46B9-BC5F-9C04DADDD5D7} (default) : Enhanced Storage Data Source
{b155bdf8-02f0-451e-9a26-ae317cfd7779} (default) : nethood delegate folder
```

Keith

Answer (score 0):

i had exactly same issue ... tried different ports etc ... still just showing 'USB MTP Device' but no files.

Then with Device Manager i found the 'USB MTP Device' under 'Portable Devices', and in Properties-->Driver(tab) disabled the driver while the camera was still connected with USB cable, then re-enabled the driver ... suddenly the name in Explorer and in Device Manager changes to 'HERO' ... and i can browse all the files in Explorer